# How to avoid NPEs from default parameters in mocked classes?

Tags: kotlin, mockito

Here's a simplified version of what I want to test with Mockito:

```
class UnderTest {
    fun doSomething() {
        foo.doAnything()
    }
}

class Foo {
    fun doAnything(bar: Bar = Bar())
}

class TestUnderTest {
    @Mock
    var underTest: UnderTest

    @Test
    fun testDoSomething() {
        underTest.doSomething() // Causes NPE
    }
}
```

`UnderTest` is being tested. Its dependencies, like `foo`, are mocked. However, when my tests call `UnderTest.doSomething()`, it crashes. `doSomething()` calls `Foo.doAnything()`, letting it fill in the null parameter with the default - and the code that runs in that default parameter initialization is outside of the control of my test, as it's inside the static, synthetic method created for the byte code.

Is there a magical Mockito solution to get around this very situation? If so, I would love to hear it. Otherwise, I believe the options I have are:

1. To use PowerMock or Mockk to be able to mock things Mockito can't
2. To change `Foo` to have two `doAnything()` methods; one would have zero parameters, would call `Bar()` and pass it to the other.
3. To change `Foo.doAnything()` to accept a nullable parameter, then to have the *body* of the function call `Bar()` and use it.

Comment: Can you please add your test class? Thanks!

Comment: Never really ran into this, but in theory the @JvmOverloads annotation could provide 2. automatically, however mockito might not play nice with annotations like that (as in it might not do anything as far as mockito is concerned).

Comment: @João Dias added per your request. I'm trying to keep the code simple and abstract to focus on the issue I'm asking about.

Comment: @somethingsomething I don't believe that would make a difference as that would still have a `Foo.doAnything()` method out of my control, which would have a body calling `Bar()`, leading to the NPE :/ Thanks though